# Oracle procedure to delete records in all tables of an owner

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create an Oracle procedure to delete records from multiple tables of an owner based upon a distinct count condition:

Firstly I am trying to obtain the tables for which I want to delete those records with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'Lorik' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'UT_%';
```

This results in a total of 300 tables, now all of those tables have a column named: DATE_INC

I am trying to delete records from **all of the tables** if this COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_INC) > 5.
Assuming that one of those 300 tables is named UT_NAMES:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_INC) FROM Lorik.UT_NAMES;
```

So if the count exceeds 5, then I want to delete the records with the minimum date:

```
DELETE MIN(DATE_INC) FROM Lorik.UT_NAMES;
```

Can someone please link these steps together so I can loop through each table of that owner and obtain the distinct date count and delete records based upon the above cited condition.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have u tried so far show us so that we can modify the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit simpler dynamic SQL for deleting rows, as it uses a local variable:

```
declare
  l_cnt      number;       -- counter variable
  l_min_date date;         -- MIN(date_inc)
begin
  for cur_t in (select table_name from all_tables 
                where owner = 'Lorik'          -- are you sure it is not uppercase, LORIK?
                  and table_name like 'UT%'    -- underline is wildcard character so you don't need it
               )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(distinct date_inc), min(date_inc) from ' || 
                       cur_t.table_name into l_cnt, l_min_date;
    if l_cnt > 5 then
       execute immediate 'delete from ' || cur_t.table_name ||
                         '  where date_inc = ' || l_min_date_inc;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Calculating min(date_inc) and using it is better than in my solution. But I would prefer  date_inc = :1' using l_min_date_inc instead of date_inc = ' || l_min_date_inc because if people don't use bind varibles for small sqls they don't use them for bigger ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' in PL/SQL to accomplish your goal:

```
DECLARE
  strTable  VARCHAR2(32767);
  nCount    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
                 FROM ALL_TABLES
                 WHERE OWNER = 'Lorik' AND
                       TABLE_NAME LIKE 'UT_%')
  LOOP
    strTable := aRow.OWNER || '.' || aRow.TABLE_NAME;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_INC) FROM ' || strTable
      INTO nCount;

    IF nCount > 5 THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ' || strTable ||
                           ' WHERE DATE_INC = (SELECT MIN(DATE_INC) ' ||
                                                 'FROM ' || strTable || ')';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Andrew this seems to be very basic processes.

- Declare some variables.
- Open a cursor.
- Use dynamic sql to count
- Use dynamic sql to delete
- Add some log information

_

```
declare 
    v_cnt   number;
    v_sql   varchar2(1000);
begin
    for cur in (SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'HR' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'E%')
    loop
        v_sql := 'select count(distinct department_id||''date_inc'') from '||cur.owner||'. '||cur.table_name;
        execute immediate v_sql into v_cnt;
        dbms_output.put_line (cur.table_name || ': ' || v_cnt);
        if v_cnt > 5 then
            v_sql := 'delete from '||cur.owner||'. '||cur.table_name || ' where date_inc = (select min (date_inc) from ' ||cur.owner||'. '||cur.table_name || ')';
            dbms_output.put_line (v_sql);
            -- execute immediate v_sql;
        end if;
    end loop;
    rollback;
    -- commit;
end;
```